# Extract string using iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have a `vector<string>` and using an iterator, I need to extract the entire string that the iterator points to, within a loop:

```
vector<string> v;   
auto iter = v.begin();  
while(iter != v.end()){ 
    auto s = //extract the string corresponding to the current iterator position
}
```

Since `*iter` would return me the first character of the corresponding string, how can this be done?

Comment: Why do you think `*iter` gives you the first character of the string?  Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to C++11 (which I'm assuming you do, as you've used `auto`), you can use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (const std::string &value : v)
{
    // Do something with value
}
```

Your original question stated,

> Since *iter would return me the first character of the corresponding string

This isn't correct, *iter will return a reference to the `string` at the relevant position within the vector. Your loop doesn't increment the iterator though, so you would end up with an infinite loop. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/pCe1oQDusDbJ8HjK